# Need help to understand how to deduce the value of $\cos^2\displaystyle\big(\frac{\pi}{5}\big)+\cos^2\big(\frac{2\pi}{5}\big)$

Tags: complex-numbers

I have some trouble understanding the steps provided in the book on solving the **last part of the question**.

For context purposes (and to provide the full picture), the whole question (with solution) is as follows:

> Prove de Moivre's theorem for positive integer exponents.
>   (I have no problem with this)

[image]

> Using de Moivre's theorem, show that $\sin5\theta=a \sin^5\theta+b \cos^2\theta\sin^3\theta+c\cos^4\theta\sin\theta$ , where $a,b$ and $c$ are integers to be determined. (No issue with this either)

[image]

> Express $\displaystyle\frac{\sin5\theta}{\sin\theta}$ in terms of $\cos\theta$, where $\theta$ is not a multiple of $\pi$. (Still no problem)

[image]

> Hence, find the roots of the equation $16x^4-12x^2+1=0$ in trigonometric form. (I understand this part)

[image]

> **Deduce the value of $\displaystyle\cos^2\Big(\frac{\pi}{5}\Big)+\cos^2\Big(\frac{2\pi}{5}\Big)$. (I don't understand the working given by the book)**

[image]

My question is, since it is found that $\displaystyle\cos^2\theta=\frac{3\pm\sqrt5}{8}$, how to tell that $\displaystyle\cos^2\frac{\pi}{5}=\frac{3+\sqrt5}{8}$ and how is it known that $\displaystyle\cos^2\frac{2\pi}{5}=\frac{3-\sqrt5}{8}$?

Comment: The angle $\pi/5$ is smaller than $2\pi/5$ and both are in the first quadrant. Therefore, the latter should have the smaller cosine, the smaller $X$ coordinate of the corresponding point in the unit circle.

Comment: @bulteromart Thanks for your explanation! Is there a rule or formula for your statement? (I think I haven't learnt it before)

Comment: It is a direct consequence of the geometric definition of cosine that it decreases for angles in $[0,\pi]$.

Comment: @bulteromart Got it, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Since what you asked seems to be answered in comments, here is an alternative way in case you are interested, it uses [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula) $$e^{it}=\cos t +i \sin t.\tag{*}$$

First notice that (*) implies $\cos t = \frac{1}{2}(e^{it}+e^{-it})$. Now put $z=e^{i\frac{\pi}{5}}$, and notice that $z^5=e^{i\pi}=-1$. Subsequently, we get $z^{-2}=z^{3}/z^5=-z^3$, and similarly $z^{-4}=z/z^5=-z$.

Then finally we have

\begin{align}
\cos^2 \frac{\pi}{5}+\cos^2 \frac{2\pi}{5}&= \left(\frac{1}{2}(e^{i\frac{\pi}{5}}+e^{-i\frac{\pi}{5}})\right)^2+\left(\frac{1}{2}(e^{i\frac{2\pi}{5}}+e^{-i\frac{2\pi}{5}})\right)^2\\
&=\frac{1}{4}((z+z^{-1})^2+(z^2+z^{-2})^2)\\
&=\frac{1}{4}(z^2+2+z^{-2}+z^4+2+z^{-4})\\
&=\frac{1}{4}(z^2+2-z^3+z^4+2-z)\\
&=\frac{1}{4}(3+1-z+z^2-z^3+z^4)\\
&=\frac{1}{4}\left(3+\frac{z^5+1}{z+1}\right)\\
&=\frac{3}{4}
\end{align}
where we have used $(z+1)(1-z+z^2-z^3+z^4)=z^5+1=0$.

Answer (score 0):

$$t=\pi/10 \implies 5t=\pi/2 \implies 2t=\pi/2-3t \implies \sin 2t= \sin(\pi/2-3t)$ \implies \sin 2t= \cos 3t$$
$$\implies 2\sin t \cos t=4 \cos^2 t-3 \cos t \implies 4\sin^2t+2 \sin t+1=0 \implies \sin t =\frac{\pm\sqrt{5}-1}{4}$$
Since $t=\pi/10$ is acute angle so its $\sin$ value should be positive. hence.
$$\sin \pi/10=\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{4}~~~~(1)$$
using $$\cos 2t=1-\sin^2 t \implies \cos \pi/5=\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{4}~~~(2)$$
Let $$F=\cos^2(\pi/5)+\cos^2(2\pi/5)=\cos^2(\pi/5)+[\cos(\pi/2-\pi/10)]^2=\cos^2(\pi/5)+\sin^2(\pi/10)$$
Using (1) and (2), we get
$$F=\left(\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{4}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{4}\right)^2=2(5/16+1/16)=3/4.$$